# Modifying factory value in directive Angular

Tags: angularjs, controller, scope, factory, directive

I have the following code : http://codepen.io/Andarius/pen/Ggryge .

When the user draws a 'crop_area', the `crop` button should not be disabled anymore.
Why is the value `no_crop_area` (from the `Image` factory) not updated when drawing ?
Is it a scope problem ?

Also, I'm pretty new to AngularJS and was wondering what is the best practice when passing a factory to a controller (if there is one)

Given a factory :

```
myApp.factory('myFactory', function () {
    return {foo:{bar:2}};
});
```

Is it better to do :

```
myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['myFactory',function (myFactory) {
    var self = this;
    self.foo = myFactory;
    self.bar = myFactory.bar;
}]);
```

or

```
myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['myFactory',function (myFactory) {
    var self = this;
    self.foo = myFactory;
    self.bar = self.foo.bar;
}]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have forked your code. Here is a working one.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qERpew?editors=101

The button is not getting enabled because, you are doing all the processing related to creating crop area by using javascript event handlers, so the code related to $scope (ie.angular related), will not come into effect. To have them in effect, you have to wrap the code related to $scope into `$scope.$apply(function(){ // Your $scope variable update code.})`.

PS: As per convention you should not use $scope name inside directive.Instead of that use scope.